# replacing a variable in multiple places in a string

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have a string that I want to put one variable in multiple places in it:

```
query_1 ='SELECT distinct ?a\
        WHERE { ?a rno:end_at ?b.\
        ?b rdf:type rno:Node; rno:is_extent_of ?x.\
        ?x rno:builds %s. %s a rno:Roundabout.\
        FILTER(NOT EXISTS {?a rno:builds %s})} ORDER BY ?a'%(ref_RaURI, ref_RaURI,ref_RaURI)
    print query_1
```

the above replacement works but I don't want to repeat the variable ref_RaURI, so I tried the following:

```
query_1 ='SELECT distinct ?a\
        WHERE { ?a rno:end_at ?b.\
        ?b rdf:type rno:Node; rno:is_extent_of ?x.\
        ?x rno:builds {0}. {0} a rno:Roundabout.\
        FILTER(NOT EXISTS {?a rno:builds {0}})} ORDER BY ?a'.format(ref_RaURI)
    print query_1
```

this one is returning:

```
    FILTER(NOT EXISTS {?a rno:builds {0}})} ORDER BY ?a'.format(ref_RaURI)
KeyError: ' ?a rno'
```

Using dictionary:

```
        query_1 ="SELECT distinct ?a\
        WHERE { ?a rno:end_at ?b.\
        ?b rdf:type rno:Node; rno:is_extent_of ?x.\
        ?x rno:builds %(s). %(s) a rno:Roundabout.\
        FILTER(NOT EXISTS {?a rno:builds %(s)})} ORDER BY ?a"%{'s':ref_RaURI}
    print query_1
```

returns:

```
    FILTER(NOT EXISTS {?a rno:builds %(s)})} ORDER BY ?a"%{'s':ref_RaURI}
ValueError: unsupported format character ' ' (0x20) at index 140
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Oh, dear. Do **not** use string formatting to interpolate data into a SQL query. You are opening yourself up for a SQL injection attack. Use SQL parameters instead (see your database adapter documentation).

Comment: This is a bad idea. What if the user escapes your query and inserts his own query? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: in fact it is a SPARQL query and I am trying to build the qury in my algorithm to send it to my reasoner. there is no DB ...how should I deal with it?

Comment: Are you using any library for it?

Comment: rdflib is the library I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, when using `%` sign for string formatting, you can specify keyword arguments like this (taken right from your example):

```
pattern ='SELECT distinct ?a\
    WHERE { ?a rno:end_at ?b.\
    ?b rdf:type rno:Node; rno:is_extent_of ?x.\
    ?x rno:builds %(p1)s. %(p1)s a rno:Roundabout.\
    FILTER(NOT EXISTS {?a rno:builds %(p1)s})} ORDER BY ?a'
params = dict(p1=ref_RaURI)
# equal to 
# params = {'p1': ref_RaURI}
query_1 = pattern % params
```

String formatting operator `%` has multiple options. Most common case is using it as `%s`. WIt just inserts string representation of the variable. There are other options, like `%c` - character, `%d` - digit and so on.
Besides this, it supports keyword arguments. This means, when you pass dictionary as a source for formatting, you can specify keys of the given dict for the `%` operator, like this:

```
d = {'one': 'first param', 'two': 'second param'}
print 'Few options here: %(one)s and %(two)s' % d
```

`%(one)s` means: take the value from the dict, by the key `one`, and put its string representation (`%s`). Same rule applies for all parameters. If you want just use `%(one)`, this will not work, because you need to provide type, which value should be printed in, in this `%s` stands for string.

Comment: what is s after the %(p1)? I have used it as you can see in my question defined with {}. I think the kwrd should be a string sth like 'p1':ref_RaURI

Comment: It is the same, like adding a string (`%s`), but instead it contains additional `(p1)`, which indicates the name of the kwarg to use. So it looks like this: `%(p1)s`.  It not requires curly braces (`{}`) as in `.format' function.

Comment: what is the difference between using %{'p1':ref_URI} and %dict(p1= ref_URI).. the first one has problem with {} but surprisingly the last one is really working. Why? must say that I should keep s after the %(p1)->%(p1)s

Comment: please edit your answer so that I can accept it as my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Al lthe comments about SQLInjection notwithstanding, in the general case you can use named parameters to `string.format()` like this:

```
>>> "Hello {myname} multi {myname} variable {myname}".format(myname="Tom")
'Hello Tom multi Tom variable Tom'
```

You can also use different formatting in different places:

```
>>> "0dp {v:.0f} 3dp {v:.3}".format(v=1.23)
'0dp 1 3dp 1.23'
```

Comment: I have used this either but it does not work. I guess as there are other {}s. :(